# Multiple modules RestAdapter's header injection

Tags: android, dependency-injection, retrofit, dagger

How do I inject RestAdapter Header from outside of module?

**Background**

I'm writing Android applications sharing the same API. So far I have written the API so that I have APIAdapterModule for providing RestAdapter.

```
@Module(library = true)
public class APIAdapterModule {
    @Provides @Singleton @Named("APIAdapter") 
    public RestAdapter CreateAPIAdapter() {
        RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = getRequestInterceptor();
        return new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint("http://api.domain.com")
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
                .build();
    }

    private RequestInterceptor getRequestInterceptor() {
        return new RequestInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                request.addHeader("client", "API module");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I connect to API using Retrofit Gateway via Service module

```
public interface ProfileGateway {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/profile/detail/")
    public void detail(@Field("id") int itemId, @Field("type") int type, Callback<ResponseDO> callback);
}
```

AND

```
@Module(library = true)
public class APIProfileService {

    @Inject
    ProfileGateway gateway;

    public APIProfileService() {
        ObjectGraph.create(new InnerProxy()).inject(this);
    }

    public void deleteAds(int itemId, int type, Callback<ResponseDO> callback) {
        assertNotNull(getGateway());
        getGateway().detail(itemId, type, callback);
    }

    public ProfileGateway getGateway() {
        return gateway;
    }

    @Module(injects = APIProfileService.class, includes = APIProfileModule.class)
    public class InnerProxy {

    }
}
```

This is working fine so far, I can inject it into my Android app. Now I want to set Header from Android app so that I can send correct data to API.

Basically something like:

Android Application A:

```
header("client":"App A")
header("userId":"A00011")
```

Android Application B:

```
header("client":"App B")
header("userId":"B621")
```

So how do I send the header from AppA and AppB without the API requiring the dependency on both apps? Is this possible?